# javascript with() function won't work in Opera, Chrome or Brave

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm inherited an HTML form that uses the js with() function:

```
with (document.images.myImage.style) {
    left = x + "px";
    top  = y + "px";
    visibility = "visible";     
}
```

This code "moves" an image on a graph based on the left/top settings.

Movement is normal in Firefox, IE and Edge, but not in the others...I'm not familiar enough with js to recode so it works in all the browsers.

Does anyone have recomendations on how to recode this?

Comment: It is not recommended to use `with`, and in fact, it's use is restricted if you're running in strict mode.

Comment: `with` has earned a spot on Douglas Crockford's list of the "[Bad Parts](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/bad-parts.html)" of JavaScript because it's confusing, it slows down processing, and its effect is often unpredictable.

Comment: You should also take a look at `Object.assign`. E.g. `Object. assign(document.images.myImage.style, { left: x + 'px', top: y + 'px', visibility: 'visible' })`

Comment: [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is ES6 only, isn't it? And I think its real purpose is to copy an old object's properties to a new object. It's probably overkill if you just want to update an image's position on the screen.

Comment: It's been a while since I've seen this terrible habit. It's basically like using `using namespace std;` in C++, right?

Answer (score 3):

`with(expression)` adds the `expression` to the scope search chain to the block inside the with statement.

The most direct replacement I can think of would be assigning a variable to `document.images.myImage.style` and prepending that to each line. So...

```
var style = document.images.myImage.style; 
style.left = x + "px"; 
style.top = y + "px"; 
style.visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: That's how I would do it too... And you beat me to the answer by seconds! Have an upvote ;)

Comment: I didn't know the bit about `with` checking for definition of the properties accessed. I would have figured it would have just blown up with an `x is not defined` if it wasn't found in the scope chain. I've also never used `with` so that's a silly guess...

Comment: I have an inkling that if it is not found in the object `with` is called by, it will write to a global variable. I can be wrong tho, lemme test that in a bit :)

Comment: I checked, it doesn't. If the variable is not in the scope chain, then you get a reference error :) still, this means that for each statement in the scope of `with`, JS engine will be forced to check the entire scope chain. Imagine if you have hundreds of assignment statements in there... It's not going to be pretty.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Check out this guy: https://jsfiddle.net/775jz53n/2/  - Firefox prints 3 as you may unfortunately expect. v8 (node) also prints 3 with the same code. Ultimately my solution would be to use strict mode and forget this knowledge. xD

Answer (score 3):

[`with` is a statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), like a `for` loop, not a function. What `with` does is allow you to reference properties on an object without typing out the objects name every time.

```
with(myObj) {
  x = y;
}
```

is the same as

```
myObj.x = myObj.y;
```

But it's not allowed in strict mode nor should it be used in non-strict mode (tends to be the source of a lot of bugs). So to translate any `with` code, just prefix any values coming from the object with the actual object.

```
document.images.myImage.style.left = x + 'px';
document.images.myImage.style.top = y + 'px';
document.images.myImage.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Comment: Also: `with` carries significant overhead because it has to check against the image style object to see if left, top and visibility are defined... +1 for the explanation, and the two answers are just as good as each other :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the information.

What I ended up doing is as "Mike C" suggested and replaced the with() statement using "document.images.style.xxx=" statements.

So far it works find in all the browsers I could find.

Again, the forum is amazing at letting you on to what others know/have discovered...Thanks again for all your help.